# Вопрос по С#, GUID

Tags: c#, guid

Есть клиент-серверное приложение. Один проект Library, другой WinExe.
Вот библиотечный проект:
Project ("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "program name," "program name .csproj," "{GUID}"
EndProject
Тут нужен GUID от Typelib?

Это WinExe:
Project ("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "program name. ProdUI, "" program name. ProdUI.csproj", "{GUID}"
Тут нужен GUID User Interface?

```
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch), Guid(""), TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FHidden)]
public interface DWebBrowserEvents2
```

Тут нужен GUID InterfaceType?

```
[ComImport, Guid(""), TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FOleAutomation | TypeLibTypeFlags.FDual | TypeLibTypeFlags.FHidden)]
public interface IWebBrowser2
```

Тут нужен GUID TypeLibType?

Я не очень хорошо знаю C#, немного изучила и изучаю. Искала информацию в интернете, но запуталась.  А, с GUID проблемы у меня, не разбираюсь... Надеюсь, что изучу и научусь разбираться... Правильно ли я указала GUID's? Если я что-то не правильно сформулировала, прошу прощения.

Comment: Стоит написать подробней, что конкретно вы делаете, что ожидаете, и в чем сейчас проблема. Например, я читая все это, думаю про себя "а зачем тут вообще все это, если проекты написаны (наверно) на одном языке, лежат в одном проекте (наверно), и достаточно добавить ссылку через студию одного проекта в другой, и без проблем дальше использовать все его объекты?".

Comment: Надо проект с помощью GUID (как я поняла), исправить и перекинуть на новые сервера. Проекты написаны на C#. Спасибо вам большое, попробую через ссылку

Comment: Хотела узнать правильно ли я указала ссылки